# Hide cell from UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to hide cells from a UITableView. My codes are below.

When I open the app I see empty rows in my TableView[as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ijNz.jpg)

How can I hide or remove(not delete) empty cells from UITableView?

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FeedTableViewCell
    
    let row = self.items[indexPath.row]
    
    cell.lblTitle.text = row.title
    cell.isHidden = !checkCurrentUser(email: row.email)
   
    return cell
}
```

I added filtered array but then I take different error [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0eif.png). My new codes are below. How can I solve this problem?

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FeedTableViewCell
    
    
    let row = self.items[indexPath.row]
    self.items = self.items.filter{checkCurrentUser(email: $0.email)}
    cell.lblTitle.text = row.title
    //cell.isHidden = !checkCurrentUser(email: row.email)
    
    
    
    return cell
}
```

Whole codes are below

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class OyuncularVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    
    var items = [ItemModel]()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        tblView.tableFooterView = UITableViewHeaderFooterView()
        retrieveItems()
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FeedTableViewCell
        
        
        let row = self.items[indexPath.row]
        self.items = self.items.filter{checkCurrentUser(email: $0.email)} //bunu ekledim siliceksem bunu silicem aga
        cell.lblTitle.text = row.title
        //cell.isHidden = !checkCurrentUser(email: row.email)
        
        
        
        return cell
    }
 
    
   
    
    /* Retriev Items */
    
    func retrieveItems() {
        DataService.dataService.ITEM_REF.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot?) in
            
            if let snapshots = snapshot?.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                self.items.removeAll()
                print(snapshots.count)
                for snap in snapshots {
                    if let postDic = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        
                        let itemModel = ItemModel(key: snap.key, dictionary: postDic)

                        print(itemModel)
                        self.items.insert(itemModel, at: 0)
                    }
                }
                
                self.tblView.reloadData()
            }
            
        })
        
    }
    
    func checkCurrentUser(email: String) -> Bool {
        let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
        
        return email == currentUser?.email
    }
  


    }
    

}
```

Comment: Use a filtered array. like, remove data from the array which is hidden or not want to show. use this array ```self.items = self.items.filter{checkCurrentUser(email: $0.email)}```

Comment: Use an array containing all items of the data source and a second array which contains only the items to be displayed. And don't `check` anything in `cellForRow`, maintain the model.

Comment: I added filtered array but now I saw an error. Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: `numberOfRows` must always return the number of items in the actual array. And one again, don’t check or filter anything in `cellForRow` or modify the order of the data source items.

Comment: I’m new at Swift so I can’t undrestand what I should do. I understand what you mean but I dunno how I can do that :( pls help

Comment: The information in the question is too vague for a concrete suggestion.

Comment: To be specific - it's not that you are new at Swift. You are new with UITableViews, and how they work. You should never get an index out of range error. Also, cell for row at should **always** refer to the array that the table is *currently* displaying. Maybe I can help, but with what you've posted I cannot duplicate your issue.

Comment: When you add an array for filtered items and you want to display data from this array, you must reference only this array in all DataSource methods : that is including numberOfRowInSection

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I added whole codes in my viewcontroller. I hope it will help to find the error reason. Thanks for your helps again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display only the emails of the current user what don't you filter the  items in the database (applying a predicate) which is the most efficient way.

Or filter the items in the `for snap in snapshots` loop.

However if you want to keep the entire data set declare a second array

```
var items = [ItemModel]()
var filteredItems = [ItemModel]()
```

and replace

```
for snap in snapshots {
    if let postDic = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        
        let itemModel = ItemModel(key: snap.key, dictionary: postDic)

        print(itemModel)
        self.items.insert(itemModel, at: 0)
    }
}
```

with the following it performs the check in the loop

```
let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
self.filteredItems.removeAll()
for snap in snapshots {
    if let postDic = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        
        let itemModel = ItemModel(key: snap.key, dictionary: postDic)

        print(itemModel)
        self.items.insert(itemModel, at: 0)
        if itemModel.email == currentUser?.email {
           self.filteredItems.insert(itemModel, at: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

And replace also the two data source methods with

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredItems.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FeedTableViewCell
    
    let row = self.filteredItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblTitle.text = row.title  
    return cell
}
```

And delete the method `checkCurrentUser`

Comment: Thank you so much sooooooooooo much! It's working right now thanks to you. Thanks again :) It makes me happy